# nestjs : interface in DI results in circular references, whereas using class is fine

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, circular-dependency

In order to be able to inject different repositories, I have created a generic abstract class. This class implements a simple generic interface.

All repo classes for the app entities therefore should extend this abstract class and implements at least the generic Repo interface..

Entities are TypeOrm entities, nothing fancy here.

I need now to inject the entity repository in the service that access the data of this entity.

If I direclty inject the entity Repository class, that extends the abstract repo class, this is fine. No error and all is working well.

But If I want to inject the repository via a token and using the repo interface in the constructor of the service instead of the repo class itself, I got circular reference issue.

Below is the code.
The `ProductsService` needs the `ProductsRepository` to be injected.
This `ProductsRepository` extends the `abstract repo class` that itself `extends a generic interface`

Please note that when no error, in the `ProductsService constructor`, the _repo constructor parameter is of type `ProductsRepository`.
When circular error occurs, the type of the -repo is `IProductsRepository and I'm injecting a token`.

I really do not understand where the circular ref is:

**the interface of the abstract class repo and the abstract class**

```
export interface IBaseRepository<T> {
  findAll(options?: FindManyOptions<T>): Promise<T[]>;
} 

export abstract class BaseAbstractRepository<T> implements IBaseRepository<T> {
  private entity: Repository<T>;
  protected constructor(entity: Repository<T>) {
    this.entity = entity;
  }

  public async findAll(options?: FindManyOptions<T>): Promise<T[]> {
    return await this.entity.find(options);
  }
}
```

**The ProductsRepository class that extends the abstract repo and implements the interface**

```
export type IProductsRepository = IBaseRepository<ProductsEntity>;

@Injectable()
    export class ProductsRepository extends BaseAbstractRepository<ProductsEntity> implements IProductsRepository {
      constructor(@Inject(EDatabaseProviders.DATABASE_CONNECTION) readonly _dbConnection: DataSource) {
        super(_dbConnection.getRepository<ProductsEntity>(ProductsEntity));
      }
    }
```

**The providers of the ProductsModule**

```
export enum EProductsProviders {
  VALUE = "VALUE",
  REPOSITORY = "REPOSITORY",
}

export const productsProviders: Array<Provider> = [
  {
    provide: EProductsProviders.VALUE,
    useValue: 32,
  },

  {
    provide: EProductsProviders.REPOSITORY,
    useClass: ProductsRepository,
  },
  ProductsRepository,
  ProductsService,
];
```

**The ProductsService that doesn't trigger the circular error (please note the type of the repo private parameter in constructor)**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  constructor(private readonly _repo: ProductsRepository) {} //<--- no error when using the class

  async getAll(): Promise<TProductsDtoOutput[]> {
    const resu = await this._repo.findAll({
      relations: {
        transactions: true,
      },
    });

    return resu.map((r) => {
      const { id, ...rest } = r;
      return rest as TProductsDtoOutput;
    });
  }
}
```

**the ProductService that triggers the error of circular dependency**

```
        @Injectable()
        export class ProductsService {
          constructor(
    @Inject(EProductsProviders.REPOSITORY) 
private readonly _repo: IProductsRepository) {} // <--- error  A circular dependency has been detected inside ProductsModule
        
        async getAll(): Promise<TProductsDtoOutput[]> {
            const resu = await this._repo.findAll({
              relations: {
                transactions: true,
              },
            });
        
            return resu.map((r) => {
              const { id, ...rest } = r;
              return rest as TProductsDtoOutput;
            });
          }
```

**finally the ProductsModule**

```
@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule, AuthenticationModule],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [...productsProviders],
})

export class ProductsModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your providers, this is expected. The issue here is that your `ProductsService` imports a value from the `products.providers` file, but the `products.providers` file imports the `products.service` file which is where e`ProductsService` is declared. To fix this, move your `EProductsProviders` enum to a `products.constants` file  and have the `products.service` and `products.providers` import the enum from *that* file, thus eliminating the circular file import.

Comment: thks it was the issue and moving the enum to a dedicated file fixed it.  So weird...